# Angularjs dynamic binding for ng-model

Tags: angularjs

Here is the Plunker that describe my problem with dynamic binding in Angularjs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fGgtOZ5IrJVo9QasQALc?p=preview

Before using Angularjs, I am used to using the input name/value like the following to generate desirable data structure for back end processing

```
<input type="text" name="computer[details][][purchaseddate]" />

<input type="text" name="computer[details][][warrantyperiod]" />
```

With Angularjs ng-model, it is possible to bind a complex data structure like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="computer.parts[0].name" />
```

However it does not work with dynamic property like the following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="computer.details[0].name" />
```

Angular keeps telling me that I am trying to set property 'name' to undefined 'details[0]', I am aware of that but are there any ways to get the same behavior with previous input's name/value where I can specify dynamic property without having to declare it first?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you describe your use case why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Binding to attributes that don't exist yet works. You can bind to `a.b.c` even if $scope.a does not exists. Angular creates the objects and attributes on-the-fly.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a.b.c" />
```

But you are trying to bind to an array element that does not exist yet:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a.b[0].c" />
```

Angular would have instantiate the array and then push an empty object in it and then assign it's name. Apparently this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same situation and tried everything.

This is how I was able to get dynamic values inside 2 deep ng-repeat:

JS:

```
$scope.newContact = {
    name: [],
    phone: [],
    email: [],
    notes: []
};

$scope.saveNewContact = function (idx) {
    console.log($scope.newContact.name[idx]);
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newContact.name[$index]" />
<input type="text" ng-model="newContact.phone[$index]" />
<input type="text" ng-model="newContact.email[$index]" />
<input type="text" ng-model="newContact.notes[$index]" />
<button ng-click="saveNewContact($index)">Save</button>
```